# How to deal with unequal variances in repeated measures ANOVA

Tags: self-study, anova, repeated-measures, levenes-test

Angry Birds is a video game in which you fire birds at pigs. A (fabricated) study was set up in which people played Angry Birds and a control game (Tetris) over a two-year period (one year per game). They were put in a pen of pigs for a day before the study, and after 1 month, 6 months and 12 months. Their violent acts towards the pigs were counted. The data look like this:

```
game          baseline  t1  t2  t3 
Angry Birds   2         4   4   4 
Angry Birds   3         0   1   0 
Tetris        3         3   0   2 
Tetris        4         1   4   3
```

I performed Levene's test to check if the variances between the 2 groups (Angry Birds vs. Tetris) are the same.  They are not.

A core assumption of repeated measures ANOVA is that these variances are the same.  Based on Levene's test, this assumption fails for my data.  what do I do now?  How do I perform repeated measures ANOVA when this assumption is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though there are 2 groups, Mauchly's Test of Sphericity should be run rather than Levene's. If that is significant, you can adjust your degrees of freedom to calculate your critical P-level using the Greenhouse-Gieser or Huyhn-Feldt correction. Or, just do a robust ANOVA.